# how to check the response header after sending the modified request

Tags: php, validation, jsp

I was thinking if their is any way i can check the response header or the page is rendered differently after i have modified the request header or get parameter.

Like:

```
Original:www.abc.com/index.php?a=2 
mODIFIED:www.abc.com/index.php?a=2polo
```

Now when i have appended the polo string after 2 i should see page rendered differently or it should rendered normally. But how can i check that it was rendered normally or not.

Any way i can compare normal response and the modified "request " response?

Elaboration of my problem.
I have an example.
suppose this is the original url:[http://www.lnctgroup.in/institute.php?institute=4](http://www.lnctgroup.in/institute.php?institute=4polo)

Now this is the modified one on get parameter:http://www.lnctgroup.in/institute.php?institute=4polo

You can see the page rendered normally in original case but  while appending "polo" string it shown error as mysql error may be but the page rendered differently.I just want to  compare if i am getting the same page or different page after i have modified the get post parameters.

Help

Comment: Please provide more information on what you are trying to accomplish. Are you looking to check whether the response a client receives differs based on the inclusion of different GET parameters?

Comment: I have edited the Post with example what i want to do.Kindly see if you can help.

Answer (score 1):

If you would have gone through this then you shouldn't  have asked this question.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.httpresponse.php

Go through it first.I cant prepare fully functional code for you here.

Comment: That gave me idea @Injector.I will update the post as soon as i get something near.